# "includes" function is not work in internet explore in angular2 project

Tags: javascript

I am beginner of angular2. I use "includes" method in function of my angular2 project.But "includes" method is not work in Internet explore.

```
public filterByTags(event: any) {
    this.**selectedTags**.push(event);
    console.log(this.selectedTags)
    this.data = this.**originalData**.filter(
        item => {
            return this.selectedTags.every(tag => {
                if (item.tags.length == 0) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return item.tags.includes(tag.id)
                }
            });
        }
    );
}
```

SelectedTags and originalData both are arrays. I need to check is there are selected tags value in originalDat array??
How I compare these two arrays using "indexOf" without using "includes"

Comment: Have you tried `import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es7/array';`?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4128#issuecomment-274053739

Comment: No. I didnot tried.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Angular.

`includes` is a [standard method on Array objects in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) which was introduced in ES2016 and is thus too new to be supported by Internet Explorer.

MDN showcases a [polyfill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill_(programming)) to add support in out of date browsers:

> ```
> // https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.includes
> if (!Array.prototype.includes) {
>   Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'includes', {
>     value: function(searchElement, fromIndex) {
>
>       if (this == null) {
>         throw new TypeError('"this" is null or not defined');
>       }
>
>       // 1. Let O be ? ToObject(this value).
>       var o = Object(this);
>
>       // 2. Let len be ? ToLength(? Get(O, "length")).
>       var len = o.length >>> 0;
>
>       // 3. If len is 0, return false.
>       if (len === 0) {
>         return false;
>       }
>
>       // 4. Let n be ? ToInteger(fromIndex).
>       //    (If fromIndex is undefined, this step produces the value 0.)
>       var n = fromIndex | 0;
>
>       // 5. If n ≥ 0, then
>       //  a. Let k be n.
>       // 6. Else n < 0,
>       //  a. Let k be len + n.
>       //  b. If k < 0, let k be 0.
>       var k = Math.max(n >= 0 ? n : len - Math.abs(n), 0);
>
>       function sameValueZero(x, y) {
>         return x === y || (typeof x === 'number' && typeof y === 'number' && isNaN(x) && isNaN(y));
>       }
>
>       // 7. Repeat, while k < len
>       while (k < len) {
>         // a. Let elementK be the result of ? Get(O, ! ToString(k)).
>         // b. If SameValueZero(searchElement, elementK) is true, return true.
>         if (sameValueZero(o[k], searchElement)) {
>           return true;
>         }
>         // c. Increase k by 1. 
>         k++;
>       }
>
>       // 8. Return false
>       return false;
>     }
>   });
> }
> ```